# How to achieve this type of transition?

Tags: transitions, mask

I've been looking everywhere to try to figure this out. I am trying to figure out how to make a video transition where the background changes before everything else. Is this just done with a mask?

https://instagram.com/p/BF-K-V5ges1/

Comment: Yes. It's a very fast transition so depending on the footage you can also try using a *luma key* or some kind of color key for a rough matte. Your favorite software package is?

Answer (score 2):

According to the comments on that page, it is rotoscoped - which is ([from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotoscoping))

> the technique of manually creating a matte for an element on a live-action plate so it may be composited over another background.